# How to use dapr nats io jetstream with Go

Tags: go, dapr

I am using dapr ,to use its pub sub configuration  and using dapr go sdk to publish the messages .
With redis its working fine ,but when I am using nats.io jetstream its giving me error stream doesn't exists which ,even I am creating stream too

`pubsub.yml` I am using to run the dapr side car

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: order_pub_sub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.jetstream
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: natsURL
    value: "nats://localhost:4222"
  - name: name
    value: "connection name"
  - name: durableName
    value: "consumer durable name"
  - name: queueGroupName
    value: "queue group name"
  - name: startSequence
    value: 1
  - name: startTime # in Unix format
    value: 1630349391
  - name: deliverAll
    value: false
  - name: flowControl
    value: false
```

And this is the go code

```
//dependencies
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "strconv"
    dapr "github.com/dapr/go-sdk/client"
)

//code
var (
    PUBSUB_NAME = "order_pub_sub"
    TOPIC_NAME  = "orders"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        time.Sleep(5000)
        orderId := rand.Intn(1000-1) + 1
        client, err := dapr.NewClient()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer client.Close()
        ctx := context.Background()
    //Using Dapr SDK to publish a topic
        if err := client.PublishEvent(ctx, PUBSUB_NAME, TOPIC_NAME, []byte(strconv.Itoa(orderId))); 
        err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        log.Println("Published data: " + strconv.Itoa(orderId))
    }
}
```

I just want to know what will be the relevant names in nats ,like for topic and pubsub_name ,Or anyone able can help ?